# How to retrieve substring which is outside of brackets in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want the text which is outside of brackets, for eg.

Text is - Outside (inside)

and what I expect is - Outside

Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) & use `indexOf` to get the first `(`. This will extract all the characters before first `(`

```js
let str = 'Outside (inside)'

let substr = str.slice(0, str.indexOf('('));
console.log(substr.trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove all bracketed text from the string you could use

```js
let str = 'Outside (inside)test(d 342 dd3d)dd(t423t t)dd()fasf(fsdfds32dfs)';
console.log(str.replace(/(\([\w\d ]*\))+/g, ''))
```